# Why do specialised overload signatures work only with methods but not properties?

Tags: typescript

You can have a specialised overload signature for a method but not for property, why is that?

```
//ok
interface Test {
    method(foo : string);
    method(foo : "bar");
} 

//error
interface Test2 {
    propertyFoo : string;
    propertyFoo : "bar";
}
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for union types is on the Typescript [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) for the 1.4 release. See the [ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/824) for the discussion, but it would allow a property to be declared like this:

```
interface Test2 {
    propertyFoo : string | number;
}
```

It wouldn't make sense to "overload" a property as in your example, as "bar" is already a string. With a function, the return type may differ depending on the specific argument, so overloading is useful for better type safety & code completion. There are no such benefits for property types.